# Run a task when another task was canceled in C#

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, cancellationtokensource

I have the following requirements:

- launch Task1,2 in parallel.
- Task 5 will launch when 1 of 2 Tasks 1,2 is completed.
- Task 4 will launch only when Task 5 is cancelled.

Below is my code but it is not working. Is it possible that I want to launch a task when another task is cancelled?

```
Task.WhenAny(runTask1(), runTask2()).ContinueWith((t0) => 
{
    runTask5();
    
    if (runTask5().Status == TaskStatus.Canceled)
    {
        runTask4();
    }
});
```

Comment: `ContinueWith` has an argument that allows you to run the continuation on a given state of the preceding task - you want `OnlyOnCancelled`. Also, don't forget `await` as appropriate. Alternatively, stop trying to do this with `ContinueWith` - continuations are a bit tricky, and especially so when combined with awaits. A try-catch will allow you to do the same thing in a more straightforward manner, with fewer oddities to deal with.

Comment: _["In conclusion, I do not recommend using ContinueWith at all, unless you are doing dynamic task parallelism (which is extremely rare). In modern code, you should almost always use await instead of ContinueWith."](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/01/a-tour-of-task-part-7-continuations.html)_, Cleary, S.

Comment: But I do this in a void EventHandler which is not safe to use async void, is there a safer way?

Comment: [async avoid should be avoided, except in case of async event handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
_ = await Task.WhenAny(runTask1(), runTask2());
try
{
   await runTask5();
}
catch(OperationCancelledException ex)
{
   await runTask4();
}
```

You can `await` `Task`s inside `catch` and `finally` blocks since C# 6.